# How to properly make a query for excel worksheets using ADO?

Tags: excel, vba, ado

Below is the data I am trying to query:

[image]

I ran the code that was found in this documentation in this [microsoft documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/tn-archive/ee692882(v=technet.10)?redirectedfrom=MSDN) as shown below:

```
Sub query()

On Error Resume Next

Const adOpenStatic = 3
Const adLockOptimistic = 3
Const adCmdText = &H1

Set objConnection = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
Set objRecordset = CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")

connectionString = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0; Data Source=C:\Users\Sun-Lap\Desktop\Sample (Payroll).xlsm; Extended Properties=""Excel 8.0; HDR=YES"";"
objConnection.Open connectionString
objRecordset.Open "Select * FROM [DailyTimeRecord$] Where Person = JOHN", _
    objConnection, adOpenStatic, adLockOptimistic, adCmdText

Do Until objRecordset.EOF
    Wscript.Echo objRecordset.Fields.Item("Date"), _
        objRecordset.Fields.Item("Person")
    objRecordset.MoveNext
Loop

End Sub
```

`On Error Resume Next` causes my application to infinitely run and hangs my application.

I tried replacing `Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0` to  `Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0` based on a suggestion. I also tried to replace `Extended Properties=""Excel 8.0; HDR=YES"";` to `Extended Properties=""Excel 12.0 Macro; HDR=YES"";`

But I still get an error on `objRecordset.Open "Select * FROM [DailyTimeRecord$] Where Person = JOHN", _
    objConnection, adOpenStatic, adLockOptimistic, adCmdText`

I get an Runtime error: `No value for given for one or more required parameters`

Comment: That's VBScript, not VBA. `wscript.echo` is not a native VBA command.

Comment: @Rory I was actually wondering as it looked unusual.. I had a question tagged as VBA but one suggestion sent this reference which used VBScript and they looked similar

Comment: Your WHERE clause should read: `Where Person = 'JOHN'"`

Comment: I get a `Compile error: Expected: expression` error even when I use double quotes `Where Person = ""JOHN"""`

Comment: You should be using *single* quotes as in the example I posted.

Comment: As Rory writes, you need to put the name in Single quotes, but in the long term you will benefit of using `ADODB.parameter` to pass a parameter in a query.

Comment: @Rory Sorry for that. the problem was there was no underscore (for the continuation to the next line) after I edited the code and caused it to error but yes the quotes was needed. I just have to find the VBA equivalent to the `Wscript.echo` now

Comment: Use `debug.print`  instead

Comment: @Storax Oh alright yea that works it just works like any other object. I just got confused as I thought there were huge differences in VBscript and made me question the entire thing lol. Yep this is working now appreciate all the help